# Slide down <li> of current <ul> being clicked

Tags: jquery, html, css

So I'm trying to slide down the `<li>` of a submenu when the parent `<ul>` is being clicked but for some reason nothing happens when I click the `<ul>`. I am currently using this code:

HTML:

```
<div class="mobile-home-second-menu clearfix">
    <ul class="home-second-menu clearfix">
        <li class="first-menu-item">
            <a href="#">Main category</a>
            <ul class="submenu">
                <li class="second-menu-item">
                    <a href="#">Subcategory</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('ul.home-second-menu').click(function() {
    $(this).next('li').slideDown('normal');
});
```

CSS:

```
ul.submenu{ display:none; }
*Rest of the CSS is irrelevant*
```

For some reason the `.next()` call isn't working. When I remove the `.next` and change the `slideDown()` to `addClass()`, it works (it adds a class to ul.home-second-menu like it should). I've been looking at this for way too long now and it's probably a simple mistake but any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please check solution given below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not working because you don't have `.next()` sibling item of the clicked `ul.home-second-menu`.

Instead you should bind the `click` event on list items:

```js
    $('ul.home-second-menu li').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      if ($(this).siblings('li').find('ul.submenu:visible').length) {
        $('ul.submenu').slideUp('normal');
      }
      $(this).find('ul.submenu').slideToggle('normal'); // show the respective one.
    });
```

```css
.submenu {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mobile-home-second-menu clearfix">
  <ul class="home-second-menu clearfix">
    <li class="first-menu-item">
      <a href="#">Main category</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li class="second-menu-item">
          <a href="#">Subcategory</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="first-menu-item">
      <a href="#">Main category</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li class="second-menu-item">
          <a href="#">Subcategory</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't know who downvoted this, but this works exactly like I asked. So thanks for the quick response Jai! Marked as answer. Just a small question: How can I make it work that when the UL is clicked again, it slides back up. And when another UL with the same class is being clicked the open UL closes and the current one slides down?

Comment: @StefanNeuenschwander You can check the updated one.

Comment: @StefanNeuenschwander `.slideToggle()` is the method you are looking for.

Comment: Hmm for some reason it doesn't slide anymore, it does notice the click function but nothing happens to it edit; never mind, I changed the name of the ul class my bad. Works like a charm, thanks mate!

Comment: @StefanNeuenschwander have added a snippet check it if this is something you are looking for.

Comment: This is exactly I was looking for :)

Answer (score 2):

what is hidden is the `ul`, not the `li` you are adressing

Answer (score -1):

Please try below solution -

```js
$('ul.home-second-menu>li>a').click(function(){
    $(this).next('ul').slideDown();
});
```

```css
ul.submenu{display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mobile-home-second-menu clearfix">
    <ul class="home-second-menu clearfix">
        <li class="first-menu-item">
            <a href="#">Main category</a>
            <ul class="submenu">
                <li class="second-menu-item">
                    <a href="#">Subcategory</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @downvoter please give specific reason behind downvote. Some guys are here for downvote only even they don;t know what is the questions and what is this answer.

Answer (score -1):

When you try to animate something that is hidden or doesn't have a height set before its done animating jQuery wont know how to animate it.

You should also make use of slideToggle and pass a parameter of time to it. 
Instead of using `next`, use `children`.

```js
$('.menu').click(function(event) {
 $(this).children('li').slideToggle('fast');
});
```

```css
.menu li {
  display: none;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="menu">
  Hey, click at me
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```